# jQuery Deferred object callback args & dynamically building?

Tags: jquery

I saw this code at the jQuery site :

```
 1:  var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
        .done(function() { alert("success"); })
        .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
        .always(function() { alert("complete"); });

   2: // perform other work here ...

     // Set another completion function for the request above
   3:  jqxhr.always(function() { alert("second complete"); });
```

2 questions :

1. I heard that the callback functions **arguments** of `success` , `error` , `complete` being transferred  to `done` , `fail` , `always` respectively.

   [image]

   So if I want to use the **jqXHR** obj in  always callback , How can i know from where he came (`error` or `success`) - because the `params order` in the method signature is **different** !!!

   //here it is at place 3

[image]

```
//here it is at place 1
```

[image]

2. I also heard that deferred objects help us to build the callback functions dynamically. (as we can see in '`3:`')

   I don't understand why will I ever need it ? by the time I got the Section `3:` - the ajax call has **already** been made and alerted completed. In what scenarios the section `3:` comes into action?

Comment: If you're using Firefox and have Firebug you could use console.log(jqXHR) in the always function to see what you get.

Comment: @Alex are u serious ? I need to check it via runtime ...

Comment: `complete()` is not meant to perform operations where it matters if the request was successful or not but to perform generic actions such as cleaning up things, re-enabling a disabled button, etc.

Comment: ? $.ajax({}).always(function(jqXHR){console.log(jqXHR});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`complete()` is not meant to perform operations where it matters if the request was successful or not but to perform generic actions such as cleaning up things, re-enabling a disabled button, etc.

However, you could check if the first argument `=== jqxhr` (the return value of `$.ajax`) - if the check is true, you know there was an error.

Comment: you mean to check if its object type ? what about if i did return a json object from server ? how would i distinguish ?